# Contains and Regex Returns true but not with exact match

Tags: c#, regex, contains

I am stumped on how to figure out the condition.  Basically I have information from a list into a string to use Contains and Regex.  I need to figure out if the user selected the "Other" option and if so then do something.  However in the same list there are additional values to choose from that start with "Other" as well.

Example Data:

- Fire Material
- Other
- Other Chemical

Example Code:

```
if(MaterialList.ToString().Contains("Other"))
    {   
"Do This If Other Is Selected";
    }
else
    {
"Do That If Other Isn't Selected";
    }
```

It works fine if the user selects just "Other" however, if the user doesn't select "Other" but selects "Other Chemical" the condition still returns true.

I have also tried the following and it behaves the same:

```
public static bool ExactMatch(string input, string match)
    {

    return Regex.IsMatch(input, string.Format(@"{0}", Regex.Escape(match)));
    //actually doesn't find the exact match - just a portion of the string

    }
```

Probably Contains or Match shouldn't be used but not sure how to solve the problem.

Comment: Is your MaterialList an actual list or just a specially formatted string?

Comment: I have the feeling `MaterialList` is just a string and this question is "Why, if I ask whether string `a` *contains* string `b` in one of two different ways, do I get what I asked for rather than a result indicating whether string `a` *is exactly equal to* string `b`."

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could use Linq instead:

```
if (MaterialList.Any(m => m == "Other"))
    ...
```

Comment: You're assuming `MaterialList` is a sequence of strings. If you can call `ToString` on it and get a string containing `Other`, that seems unlikely.

Comment: Well that's a good point (even though calling ToString() on a string seems odd), then I guess you would have to introduce some kind separators or else I don't see how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.EndsWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function in your case

From MSDN:

> Determines whether the end of this string instance matches the
>   specified string.

try this:

```
if(MaterialList.ToString().EndsWith("Other"))
{   
   "Do This If Other Is Selected";
}
else
{
   "Do That If Other Isn't Selected";
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks. But when I choose both "Other" and "Other Chemical" it returns false.  But if I only choose "Other" it returns true.

Comment: can you choose two items from list?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
public static bool ExactMatch(string input, string match)
{
    return input == match;
}
```

or you're sick by `do-everything-with-regex`?

Comment: Are you sick at `one-line-method-anything`? :P

Comment: Thanks. But when I choose both "Other" and "Other Chemical" it returns false.  But if I only choose "Other" it returns true.

Comment: @YoryeNathan well, it will be inlined by compiler anyway, because method body is lower than 64bytes

Comment: @Mus yes, as expected, it's what is called `exact match`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  Figured it out.

```
if(MaterialsList.ToString().Split('\t').Contains("Other"))
```